# critical error : it apears that the flowing instance of netbeans is running

Tags: windows-7

My OS is windows 7 64-bit and I use NetBeans IDE 8.2. When I was uninstalling it, the following error occured:

> critical error: it appears that the following instance of NetBeans IDE is still running

How do I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to fix it?

You need to delete the .lock file indicated in the error message.  By default the file is hidden, so you will need to enable the ability to view hidden files, in order to actually see it.

The `.lock` file will be in `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\`, you need to manually delete it, in order to uninstall NetBeans 8.1